# AnnotationHub installation ‘Rcpp’ 1.0.6 is already loaded, but >= 1.0.7 is required

Tags: r, rcpp, bioconductor

I am currently trying to install `AnnotationHub` but I am running into problems. I use `R` 4.0.4,  `renv` (version 0.15.4) and `BiocVersion` 3.12.

When I run `BiocManager::install("AnnotationHub")`, I get the following error:

```
Warning message:
This project is configured to use R version '4.1.1', but '4.0.4' is currently being used. 
* installing *source* package ‘AnnotationHub’ ...
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
** testing if installed package can be loaded from final location
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘AnnotationHub’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 namespace ‘Rcpp’ 1.0.6 is already loaded, but >= 1.0.7 is required
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
```

My `.libPaths()` look something like this:

```r
[1] "/test_renv/renv/library/R-4.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"
[2] "/usr/prog/R/4.0.4/lib64/R/library"
```

I thought that the error message was very straight forward and reinstalled `Rcpp` (`install.packages("Rcpp")`). Then I ran `packageVersion("Rcpp")` which returned `1.0.8.3`.
I restarted my R session and reran `BiocManager::install("AnnotationHub")`, but the exact same error message occured. Also if I run `library(Rcpp)` before installing `AnnotationHub`.

When I run `sessionInfo()` after restart, it looks like this:

```
R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/prog/OpenBLAS/0.2.20-GCC-6.4.0-2.28/lib/libopenblas_haswellp-r0.2.20.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices datasets  utils     methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.4 tools_4.0.4    renv_0.15.4
```

I would greatly appreciated any insights, why this might occur and how I can fix it.

(I have also posted the issue on StackOverflow, because I think that this is not necessary a Bioconductor related problem)

Comment: You might want to file an issue at https://github.com/rstudio/renv/issues; the fact that `BiocManager::install("AnnotationHub")` isn't finding the right version of Rcpp here is surprising to me.

Answer (score 3):

The error message is very straightforward, yes, and your solution goes in the right direction. But you apparently have a mix here between an `renv` environment and your usage of the standard `install.packages` and `BiocManager::install`. If you need an environment with specific versions, then stick to `renv::install` and so on to set a proper lock file. Trying to use `install.packages` is pointless if the lock file is enforcing an old version (of Rcpp and/or other packages). Otherwise, just remove the lock file or disable the environment.

Comment: Thank you so much. `renv::install("bioc::AnnotationHub")` ended up working.

Comment: Glad to hear it is working (and I had already upvoted Inaki answer yesterday) but this is not a new issue so I tagged it now as a duplicate.

Comment: Note that this is a different issue than the Seurat one though. There, it was just a question of restarting the R session. Here, this doesn't help, because there's a `renv` lockfile in use that keeps pointing to an old version for each restart.